# invalid solidity type

Tags: solidity, web3js, returndata

solidity 0.5.0
web3@ 0.20.7

In my contract.There's a function (view) returns a struct type.
When I used web3.js to call this function, I got "Error: invalid solidity type!: tuple".
I know that this problem is solved in web3@1.0.0-beta.36.
But my Dapp is using web@0.20.7.
I don't want to change to 1.0.0, because my app is not small.
Is there a solution to this problem in web3 0.20.7?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Are we supposed to guess how you call this function from your web3 script??? BTW, there is no problem on web3.js v0.20.x, related to functions which return a tuple. You can change your contract's function to return a tuple instead of a struct. Otherwise, you'll need to switch to web3.js v1.x. In general, you should choose between [Solidity 0.4.x, Truffle 4.x, Web3 0.x] and [Solidity 0.5.x, Truffle 5.x, Web3 1.x].

Answer (score 1):

You may use `web3.eth.call` function like this:

```js
var myContract = new web3.eth.Contract (myContractABI, myContractAddress);
var result = web3.eth.call ({
  from: fromAddress, // Optional
  to: myContractAddress,
  data: myContract.methods.myMethod(... call parameters ...).encodeABI ()
});
```

Then you will need to somehow decode returned `result` yourself.  To make this work with your version of web3js you may also need to manually edit you contract's ABI and change return type for your function from struct to nothing.

See [documentation](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.5.12/abi-spec.html#handling-tuple-types) for details how structs are packed by ABI.